# Override -tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath: to display info

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to display info in my `UITableViewCell`. I want to be able to swipe to the left on the cell and instead of displaying the deleteCellButton I want to see a piece of content.
How do I override this method to do just that.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}
```

Your Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use below delegate method

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return @"Some Content";
}
```

//Normal Delegate Method

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Determine if it's in editing mode
    if (self.tableView.editing)
    {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }

    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

Hope it helps you..!

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
    {

       //add code here for when you hit delete
       NSLog(@"selected row is : %d",indexPath.row);

           NSString *frndName = [[sections valueForKey:[[[sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            NSString *remove = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Are you sure want to remove '%@' from your friends?",frndName];

            UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:remove delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Remove" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
            av.title = frndName;
            [av show];


     }

}


- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   NSLog(@"editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath");

    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}


-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForDeleteConfirmationButtonForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   return @"Remove";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `tableView:editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:` method of `UITableViewDelegate` if you want to show more actions.
Have a look at the `UITableViewRowAction` class to see what's possible:
[here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewRowAction_class/%20UITableViewRowAction)